# Calculate maximum-minimum of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
            a           b           c
Utah    0.907184    0.000049    0.550308
NY      0.129423    1.606726    2.041340
DC      0.228202    1.041567    0.007727
Texas   0.947254    0.000211    0.346336
```

I want to apply this function to my dataframe:

```
func=lambda x: max(x)-min(x)
```

When I call `df.apply(func)`, it applies the function to each column:

```
a    0.817831
b    1.606677
c    2.033613
dtype: float64
```

I want to calculate the maximum value in my dataframe (2.041340, NY) minus the minimum value (0.000049, Utah) and return `2.041291`

Comment: Can you show your expected output? All the cells in the 4x3 result will be the same, won't it?

Comment: yea, a minute please

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want a column that shows the minimum and maximum value in each row? Going from a 3x3 to a 4x3?

Comment: good to have more wisdom to be added. go ahead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using **`numpy`**'s ["peak to peak"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html) function:

```
>>> df.values.ptp()
2.0412909999999997
```

If you want a 4x3 result, just assign it back in-place:

```
df[:] = df.values.ptp()
```

Comment: ooh, this is quite smart.

Comment: nice! i didn't know that existed!

Comment: Great! further on this function, I would expect `df.ptp() ` to return a series, which is a result of calculated each column. But it returned a error, df.ptp() does not exist for dataframe now?

Comment: @S.Gu `ptp` is a NumPy ndarray method, it is not implemented in Pandas. So if you want to calculate it for each column, you'd do so passing an axis in NumPy - `pd.Series(df.values.ptp(axis=0))`

Comment: Just note that your function does the exact same thing (and returns the same result), that `pd.Series(df.values.ptp(axis=0))` does.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.values.max() - df.values.min()
```

calculates the scalar difference between the highest & lowest values in the data frame.

for this data frame, this gives the output:

```
2.0412909999999997
```

Comment: yea, seems a no-brainer... why did I struggle that much...thank you

Comment: @S.Gu I would've posted this 10 minutes ago had it not been for the "return a DataFrame of 4x3" in your question which you've just removed. Next time, please write your question properly _before_ you publish it.

Comment: So can you do it if you use 'apply' or 'map'

Comment: @S.Gu Sure, but you shouldn't. That will be needlessly slower and more complicated.

Comment: @S.Gu, do you want to build a 4x3 matrix where `2.04129` is in all the cells?

Comment: You should fix your input to `df.values.max(0)-df.values.min(0)`